# Rcpp with OpenMP Check fail due to registration problems

Tags: r, openmp, rcpp

I am building a R package using Rcpp and OpenMP. When doing the CRAN check, I get Notes leading to errors when building. Suggestions from RcppGallery, Stackoverflow, Writing R Extensions and exemplary packages did not help so far. I tried out various combinations for the Makevars and tried to follow every possible detail provided from those sites, but it still does not solve the following notes:

```
N  checking foreign function calls (1.3s)
   Registration problem:
     symbol '_GeneralizedUmatrix_trainstepC2' not in namespace:
      .Call(`_GeneralizedUmatrix_trainstepC2`, vx, vy, DataSampled, 
          BMUsampled, Lines, Columns, Radius, toroid)
   See chapter 'System and foreign language interfaces' in the 'Writing R
   Extensions' manual.
```

```
N  checking R code for possible problems (9.7s)
   trainstepC2: no visible binding for global variable
     '_GeneralizedUmatrix_trainstepC2'
   Undefined global functions or variables:
     _GeneralizedUmatrix_trainstepC2
```

Makevars.Win/Makevars:

```
PKG_LIBS =  $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS) $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
CXX_STD = CXX11
```

R/RcppExports:

```
Delta3DWeightsC <- function(vx, Datasample) {
    .Call(`_GeneralizedUmatrix_Delta3DWeightsC`, vx, Datasample)
}

addRowWiseC <- function(WeightVectors, DataPoint) {
    .Call(`_GeneralizedUmatrix_addRowWiseC`, WeightVectors, DataPoint)
}

trainstepC <- function(vx, vy, DataSampled, BMUsampled, Lines, Columns, Radius, toroid) {
    .Call(`_GeneralizedUmatrix_trainstepC`, vx, vy, DataSampled, BMUsampled, Lines, Columns, Radius, toroid)
}

trainstepC2 <- function(vx, vy, DataSampled, BMUsampled, Lines, Columns, Radius, toroid) {
    .Call(`_GeneralizedUmatrix_trainstepC2`, vx, vy, DataSampled, BMUsampled, Lines, Columns, Radius, toroid)
}
```

src/RcppExports:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

#ifdef RCPP_USE_GLOBAL_ROSTREAM
Rcpp::Rostream<true>&  Rcpp::Rcout = Rcpp::Rcpp_cout_get();
Rcpp::Rostream<false>& Rcpp::Rcerr = Rcpp::Rcpp_cerr_get();
#endif

// Delta3DWeightsC
arma::cube Delta3DWeightsC(Rcpp::NumericVector vx, Rcpp::NumericVector Datasample);
RcppExport SEXP _GeneralizedUmatrix_Delta3DWeightsC(SEXP vxSEXP, SEXP DatasampleSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< Rcpp::NumericVector >::type vx(vxSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< Rcpp::NumericVector >::type Datasample(DatasampleSEXP);
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(Delta3DWeightsC(vx, Datasample));
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}
// addRowWiseC
NumericMatrix addRowWiseC(NumericMatrix WeightVectors, NumericVector DataPoint);
RcppExport SEXP _GeneralizedUmatrix_addRowWiseC(SEXP WeightVectorsSEXP, SEXP DataPointSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< NumericMatrix >::type WeightVectors(WeightVectorsSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< NumericVector >::type DataPoint(DataPointSEXP);
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(addRowWiseC(WeightVectors, DataPoint));
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}
// trainstepC
arma::cube trainstepC(Rcpp::NumericVector vx, Rcpp::NumericVector vy, Rcpp::NumericMatrix DataSampled, Rcpp::NumericMatrix BMUsampled, double Lines, double Columns, double Radius, bool toroid);
RcppExport SEXP _GeneralizedUmatrix_trainstepC(SEXP vxSEXP, SEXP vySEXP, SEXP DataSampledSEXP, SEXP BMUsampledSEXP, SEXP LinesSEXP, SEXP ColumnsSEXP, SEXP RadiusSEXP, SEXP toroidSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< Rcpp::NumericVector >::type vx(vxSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< Rcpp::NumericVector >::type vy(vySEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< Rcpp::NumericMatrix >::type DataSampled(DataSampledSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< Rcpp::NumericMatrix >::type BMUsampled(BMUsampledSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< double >::type Lines(LinesSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< double >::type Columns(ColumnsSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< double >::type Radius(RadiusSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< bool >::type toroid(toroidSEXP);
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(trainstepC(vx, vy, DataSampled, BMUsampled, Lines, Columns, Radius, toroid));
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}
// trainstepC2
arma::cube trainstepC2(Rcpp::NumericVector vx, Rcpp::NumericVector vy, Rcpp::NumericMatrix DataSampled, Rcpp::NumericMatrix BMUsampled, double Lines, double Columns, double Radius, bool toroid);
RcppExport SEXP _GeneralizedUmatrix_trainstepC2(SEXP vxSEXP, SEXP vySEXP, SEXP DataSampledSEXP, SEXP BMUsampledSEXP, SEXP LinesSEXP, SEXP ColumnsSEXP, SEXP RadiusSEXP, SEXP toroidSEXP) {
BEGIN_RCPP
    Rcpp::RObject rcpp_result_gen;
    Rcpp::RNGScope rcpp_rngScope_gen;
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< Rcpp::NumericVector >::type vx(vxSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< Rcpp::NumericVector >::type vy(vySEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< Rcpp::NumericMatrix >::type DataSampled(DataSampledSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< Rcpp::NumericMatrix >::type BMUsampled(BMUsampledSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< double >::type Lines(LinesSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< double >::type Columns(ColumnsSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< double >::type Radius(RadiusSEXP);
    Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< bool >::type toroid(toroidSEXP);
    rcpp_result_gen = Rcpp::wrap(trainstepC2(vx, vy, DataSampled, BMUsampled, Lines, Columns, Radius, toroid));
    return rcpp_result_gen;
END_RCPP
}
```

NAMESPACE:

```
useDynLib("GeneralizedUmatrix", .registration = TRUE)

import(RcppArmadillo)
importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)

import(Rcpp)
importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)
```

DESCRIPTION:

```
Imports: Rcpp (>= 1.0.7), RcppArmadillo, ggplot2, shiny, shinyjs, png, tcltk
Suggests: DataVisualizations, rgl, grid, mgcv, reshape2, fields, ABCanalysis, plotly, deldir, methods, knitr (>= 1.12), rmarkdown (>= 0.9)
LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppArmadillo, BH
Depends: R (>= 3.0)
NeedsCompilation: yes
SystemRequirements: C++11, GNU make, pandoc (>=1.12.3, needed for vignettes)
LazyLoad: yes
LazyData: TRUE
```

Comment: My ```makevars``` files don't include the line ```CXX_STD = CXX11``` and it works perfect with omp. I have declare ```C++11``` inside ```Namespace``` file using command ```SystemRequirements: C++11```. I don't think it is related but you could try it.

Comment: There are _numerous_ packages on CRAN using OpenMP and _numerous_ posts here detaliling the ins and outs,  Just following `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()` should fix things for you.  Please try that on a new (empty) package and see if you can adjust your package to match.

Comment: @ManosPapadakis Thanks for the suggestion, but it yields the same Notes.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for your instruction. I used the structure from the skeleton but still get the same Notes.

Comment: You need to supply a section with symbol registration.  Running `compileAttributes()` should do that for you.  That has nothing to do with OpenMP so your Subject: is misleading.

Comment: I provided the RcppExports from R/ and src/ created by the compileAttributes().

Comment: As I said, you need a section such as this https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppexamples/blob/master/src/RcppExports.cpp#L87-L101 (from the `RcppExamples` package).  This is generally autogenerated and we cannot tell you why that did not work for you.

Comment: I show the complete src/RcppExports, thus this part is missing apparently.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- there is little we can do for you here as you keep too many pieces hidden.  When something gets stuck on a more "complex" problem I usually try to get back to a smaller problem, make that work and build up again. Maybe try a simpler sample?  Good luck.

Comment: I published the current version of my library on github, so that nothing more is hidden by accident. It seems (comparing to skeletons and other package examples) that everything is set up fine, but its not working. Maybe its just a rookie mistake, but at that point I am not able to figure it out by myself.
https://github.com/Quirinms/GeneralizedUmatrix/

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Is there any reason that two last parts of your RcppExports file, which you highlighted here https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppexamples/blob/master/src/RcppExports.cpp#L87-L101, are not built automatically in my package? It seems to be the only difference.
Is there any specific things to consider when using OpenMP? Maybe this can be a further error source.

Comment: It's been a loooooooong time since I had this, but I did have it.  This is a change in R itself (requiring the section) that came after this Rcpp infrastructure (i.e. `compileAttributes()`) was initially written and we first did this in a two-step, and later integrated it.  I feel like I had the same issue you have now once or twice, but it usually went away when working with clean and standard packages. I have no other tip than to follow the logic in `compileAttributes()`:  "somehow" it thinks it is not in charge and backs out to not overwrite something you have done.

Comment: I also found that relying on `compileAttributes()` and standard use of `[{Rcpp::exports]]` along with other mechanisms (such as still using `.Call()` "by hand" and/or Rcpp Modules) can lead to this.  But for (literally thousands of) normal packages it "just works" as it should.

Comment: Try removing the file `src/packagename_init.c` and re-running `compileAttributes()`.  I don't think you compared very hard or closely with what the skeleton generators prepare _as they do not add such a C file_.  When Rcpp sees it, it assumes you want to override and backs off.  You generally do not want that.

Comment: Kudos, you solved it! Thank you very much, this file was just somehow not on my radar.

Comment: "Always obvious in hindsight" but annoying til you get there.  Viel Spass mit Rcpp!